# An assertion faliure is killing me

Tags: c++, class, data-structures, stack, linked-list

I keep getting _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(phead->nBlockUse) during runtime.  I have spent 3 hours messing around with it and found that it is somehow caused by the destructor? What i have figured out was that when my stack is empty, there wasnt a problem.  but when there was something, it gave me this error.  I checked online and my destructor and i dont know what is going on.  Here are my all of my codes.

EDIT: i fixed the error but there s runtime error now...?

.cpp
I have tried

```
stack::~stack() ////PROBLEM STILL HERE??
{
     while (this)
   {

         top=top->next;
         int x,y;
         pop(x,y);
   }

}

stack::~stack()
{

   StackNode *nodePtr, *nextNode;
   nodePtr = top;
     while (nodePtr)
        {
      nextNode = nodePtr->next;
      delete nodePtr;
      nodePtr = nextNode;

   }

}
```

stack::~stack()
    {

```
while (!isEmpty()) 
{ int x,y; pop(x,y); }


}
```

Comment: You really should simplify this before you post it.

Comment: No, the edited code still won't work. You require a simple ` while (!isEmpty())
   {
       int x,y;
    pop(x,y);
   }` in the destructor.

Comment: @naveen still error, i need to update head??

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The problem is in the destructor. You are deleting the nodes there but you are not updating the `top` pointer. As a result your `isEmpty()` will malfunction as it checks the value of `top`.

How to fix?

You've already taken care of deleting a node in the `pop` function why duplicate the logic in the destructor? Keep calling `pop` from the destructor till the stack is not empty.

Comment: @Muggen: Well, he is calling `pop` only when the stack is not empty. So it'll work. But yes his pop called on an empty stack will blow.

Comment: i still cant seem to get it, will you help

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the destructor as you are not updating the top. Instead of again writing the code for deleting the elements you can simply call `pop` function in the `while` loop.

Comment: In the `isEmpty` method which is used to break the loop, you are checking the `top` pointer. Since `top` pointer is never updated, your loop never terminates and ends up deleting invalid memory locations which invoke undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Look closely at the interaction between your destructor and IsEmpty().  IsEmpty() checks `top` for nullness, but your destructor never updates top after deleting the head node.

I'd probably write the destructor like this:

```
stack::~stack()
{
  StackNode *nodePtr, *nextNode;
  nodePtr = top;

  while (nodePtr)
  {
    nextNode = nodePtr->next;
    delete nodePtr;
    nodePtr = nextNode;
  }
}
```

Comment: i pasted this in but still no go

Answer (score 1):

```
stack::~stack()                   //PROBLEM HERE??
{
   StackNode *nodePtr, *nextNode;
   nodePtr = top;
     while (!isEmpty())
   {
      nextNode = nodePtr->next;
            delete nodePtr;
      nodePtr = nextNode;

   }

}
bool stack::isEmpty()
{

   if (!top)
      return true;
   else
      return false;

}
```

Those two seem somehow wrong. Imagine your `stack` is not empty. This means `top` points to somewhere (therefor not `null`). In order for your destructor to stop from accessing memory it should not, you use `isEmpty()` which checks for `null` in top. But in this piece of code, `top` is never set to `null`. Sooner or later you start `delete`-ing memory you do not own.

Comment: so would editing: while(!isEmpty()) into while(nodePtr!=NULL) work?

Comment: @kingcong, edit your original post if you want to add a new version. Doing it on comments is not very comfortable `:P`

Comment: @kingcong, when you do a `delete x`, `x` is not set to null, it still contains the memory address of what it was pointing to, with the difference that you may not use that memory now. You need to explicitly set `x = null` after delete to avoid dangling pointers.